# Ideally it would be a rare occurrence so any affect on a customer's user experience is minimized?

Tags: grammaticality

"Ideally it would be an rare occurrence so any affect on a customer's user experience is minimized?"

Just double-checking, it is "affect" and not "effect" correct?

Comment: I just entered it in Microsoft Word. Word says "effect" should be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, **effect** is correct here.  **Affect** as a noun is almost exclusively used in its jargonistic sense from psychology, meaning (OED)

> *Psychology (and Psychiatry).* A feeling or subjective experience accompanying a thought or action or occurring in response to a stimulus; an emotion, a mood. In later use also (usually as a mass noun): the outward display of emotion or mood, as manifested by facial expression, posture, gestures, tone of voice, etc.

(The OED does list several other senses for this noun, but all of them are marked as "obsolete".)